# Easiest way to make a cyclic iterator (circulator)?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have an object that I want to travel in a continuous loop in a game. I have a series of coordinates in a `std::vector` that I want to use as waypoints.

Is there any way to make an `std::vector<T>::iterator` cyclic (also known as a circulator)?

The best I can come up with is to have two iterators and then whenever the first iterator is exhausted assign to it the value of the second (which would not be used to do anything else) but I am not even sure it will work - will the assignment operator copy whatever the iterator is using to hold the index or will it merely be referenced (and therefore will be useless after the second round)?

I want the object to travel the waypoint forever (unless it is destroyed but that doesn't happen in that method), but the iterator will only be called once for each frame and must return so that I can update the other objects in the game.

The solution must work on gcc and microsoft compiler (if it isn't possible to write it in standard C++).

Comment: I've written an iterator like that so its definitely possible =)
The only twist I remember is that the comparison operator < should return true at all time unless the iterators are equal.

Comment: On the other hand, do you really need `operator<` ? It's a bit mischievous to hide the cyclic behavior!

Answer (score 24):

Ok, now your problem is clearer :-)

Take a look at boost::iterator_facade and boost::iterator adaptor. They implement the full iterator interface and your `cycle_iterator` only as to implement a few methods like increment(), decrement():

```
template<class IteratorBase>
class cycle_iterator 
     : public boost::iterator_adaptor< 
          cycle_iterator,     // the derived class overriding iterator behavior
          IteratorBase,       // the base class providing default behavior
          boost::use_default, // iterator value type, will be IteratorBase::value_type
          std::forward_iterator_tag, // iterator category
          boost::use_default  // iterator reference type
       > 
{
  private:
     IteratorBase m_itBegin;
     IteratorBase m_itEnd;

  public:
     cycle_iterator( IteratorBase itBegin, IteratorBase itEnd ) 
       : iterator_adaptor_(itBegin), m_itBegin(itBegin), m_itEnd(itEnd)
     {}

     void increment() {
        /* Increment the base reference pointer. */
        ++base_reference();

        /* Check if past-the-end element is reached and bring back the base reference to the beginning. */
        if(base_reference() == m_itEnd)
            base_reference() = m_itBegin;
     }

     // implement decrement() and advance() if necessary
  };
```

This probably doesn't compile but should get you started.

Edit:

[boost::iterator_adaptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_adaptor.html) implements the full iterator interface in terms of few functions. It provides default implementations for `increment()`, `decrement()`, `advance()`, `distance_to()`, `equal_to()` and `dereference()` using the base iterator passed down to the `iterator_adaptor` base class.

If all you need is a forward iterator, only the `increment()` method must be implemented to wrap around once you reach the end iterator. A cyclical iterator can be bidirectional if you implement `decrement()` in a similar fashion. If `IteratorBase` is itself a random access iterator, the cycle iterator can also be random access and method `advance` and `distance_to` must be implemented using modulo operations.

Comment: +1: `iterator_adaptor` is the easiest way to write iterators, and the examples are just great (notably how to only write one adaptor and obtain both the const and non-const versions)

Comment: Is there a way to make binary operators like `!=` to work with arguments of type `cycle_iterator<IteratorBase>` and `IteratorBase`? I'm trying to compare `cycle_iterator` and "usual" iterator and need to make explicit overload in this case.

Comment: `increment()` needs work methinks -- I would think ideally that incrementing the value before `end` should give you the `begin`ning, not the `end` on a cyclical iterator.

Comment: To expand @Yakk comment, the current proposed implementation of the public method `void increment()` can cause a dereference to `m_itEnd` if used, for example, in a loop cycle. Since `end` iterator pointers usually refer to the address past the end, the `increment()` method should increment first, and then check if it is past the end, i.e. something like:
`void increment() {  ++base_reference(); if(base_reference() == m_itEnd) base_reference()=m_itBegin; }`

Answer (score 8):

`boost::iterator adaptor` is the way to go, take my word for it ;)

That being said I want to point out a few pitfalls. I don't think I can edit an existing answer, so bear with me.

Given that your base iterator is going to be a vector you need to be careful which core interface functions you need to implement. If you want your `cycle_iterator` to be a random access iterator you need all of the following:

```
increment() 
decrement()
advance(n)
distance_to(j)
```

Now `distance_to(j)` is a somewhat funny concept for a `cycle_iterator` and its semantics can get you in all kind of trouble. This can be avoided by restricting the iterator category of the adapted iterator to either forward or bidirectional. Like this:

```
template <class BaseIterator>
class cycle_iterator
  : public boost::iterator_adaptor<
        cycle_iterator                  // Derived
      , BaseIterator                    // Base
      , boost::use_default              // Value
      , boost::forward_traversal_tag    // CategoryOrTraversal
    >
{ ... };
```

In this case you only need to implement increment:

```
void increment()
{
  if (++this->base_reference() == this->m_itEnd)
  {
    this->base_reference() = this->m_itBegin;
  }
}
```

For a bidirectional you also need decrement:

```
void decrement()
{
  if (this->base_reference() == this->m_itBegin)
  {
    this->base_reference() = this->m_itEnd;
  }
  --this->base_reference();
}
```

Disclaimer: I did not run this through a compiler, so I am ready to be embarrassed.

Comment: I think that in general `distance_to(j)` can return either a positive or a negative number that, when added to an iterator, yields an iterator pointing to `j`. You might decide that you want to return either the smallest  such number that is non-negative, or such number having the smallest absolute value. In most cases, the latter probably makes most sense - or is there a strong argument otherwise (a counterexample)?

Comment: Any attempt to make a cyclic iterator a random access one is doomed. [Random access iterator requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) are incompatible with cyclic iteration concept. In particular, there is no way to establish strict total order on cyclic iterators.

Answer (score -4):

Derive your own collection from std::vector and provide your own iterator implementation that overrides the increment & decrement operators.

There are plenty of tutorials on the web. For example, take a look at [this blog post](http://goodliffe.blogspot.com/2008/11/c-stl-like-circular-buffer-part-10.html)

Comment: derive from vector?  Did you ever _try_ that?  I disagree.  Aggregate instead!

Comment: I have NEVER seen a class derived from a standard container that was better for it.  Aggregate.

Comment: I agree with the comments. Response posted in haste, repenting at leisure. However, can't delete it because it has been accepted as an answer.

Comment: There are separate discussions about deriving from standard containers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922248/is-there-any-real-risk-to-deriving-from-the-c-stl-containers. Dangers of deriving from containers have been overblown in my opinion. The examples against that involve deriving-and-adding members which is not the case here. Private inheritance is also a possibility.