# How to properly use boost::iterator_adaptor for making cycling iterator?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, iterator

I'm trying to implement cycling iterator, which is quite useful in my problem. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782019/easiest-way-to-make-a-cyclic-iterator) thread, I'm using `boost::iterator_adaptor` for this purpose, and iterator itself works fine. Implementation is much like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1782262/261217).

However, there is some problem when operating both `cycle_iterator` and "native" `IteratorBase` in the same sentence, like this:

```
vector<int> v;
vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
cyclic_iterator<vector<int>::iterator> cit(v.begin(), v.end());

if (cit != it)  // Don't compile
{
  ...
}
```

Compiler generates error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'cyclic_iterator' (or there is no acceptable conversion).

I can resolve it explicitly specifying `operator!=` in `cyclic_iterator` for `IteratorBase`. However, I need to explicitly overload `operator==`, `operator=` and so on.

Is there some more convenient way to make this stuff work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to do something like this:

```
template<class IteratorBase>
class cycle_iterator : public  // (...) 
{
    // (...)
    operator IteratorBase() {
        return base_reference();
    }
};
```

Comment: It can handle only the case `it V cit`, where V is some comparison operator, but not the assignment or even `cit V it` case.

Comment: Well, after all, I decided to add this conversion operator along with assignment operator, and not to compare `cyclic_itertor` with raw iterators at all since it might by error-prone. So I'll accept your answer :)