# Iterators for circular structures

Tags: c++, iterator, std

The following code shows what I currently have. It is an adapter for
circular data-structures. The main function shows how it is used. This
is all nice and fast but I really would like to have iterators over
the structure defined by `circ`. All approaches up till now involved
either some counting scheme (count the range if with the circulator,
build an iterator that counts increments and decrements) or boolean
values to check if the iterator has been moved to avoid begin and end
being equal.

Are there some common solutions to adapt a circular structure to
iterators? What other work-arounds are possible?

I would like to preserve the iteration speed as much as possible but
am willing to make compromises here. I would value a fully conforming
iterator over a minor speed penalty.

```
#include <cstddef> // nullptr
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/operators.hpp>

// circular structure that we want to iterate over
struct circ : private boost::noncopyable {
  unsigned int i;
  circ* next;
  circ* prev;
};

// whacked up circulator, imagine some template cream here to make it
// generic, omitted to preserve sanity
struct circulator
  : public boost::incrementable<circulator>
  , public boost::decrementable<circulator>
  , public boost::equality_comparable<circulator, circulator>
  , public boost::dereferenceable<circulator, circ*>
{
  circulator()
    : c(nullptr) {}
  circulator(circ& c) : c(&c) {}

  bool operator==(const circulator& other) const {
    return this->c == other.c;
  }

  circulator& operator++() { c = c->next; return *this; }
  circulator& operator--() { c = c->prev; return *this; }

  explicit operator bool() const { return c; }

  circ& operator*() const { return *c; }

  circ* c;
};

int main()
{
  circ a, b, c, d;
  a.next = &b; a.prev = &a; a.i = 0;
  b.next = &c; b.prev = &a; b.i = 1;
  c.next = &d; c.prev = &b; c.i = 2;
  d.next = &a; d.prev = &c; d.i = 3;
  circulator begin{a}, end{a};
  if(begin)
    do {
      std::cout << begin->i << std::endl;
      begin = ++begin;
    } while(begin != end);

  return 0;
}
```

If need be I can add some of my previous approaches, but they are
rather verbose and would add unnecessary bloat to the question.

EDIT: It would be nice if the resulting iterator would be bidirectional. Although I can give up this requirement.

Comment: Have you considered using (or at least stealing the design of) [boost::circular_buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html)?

Comment: @Robᵩ As far as I understand circular buffer is not really a circular iterator. e.g. walking over the end will not necessarily make you arrive at the beginning. I'll check it out anyway. Maybe my thinking is blurred.

Comment: See a much better (and amazingly, 3 years older) answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782019/easiest-way-to-make-a-cyclic-iterator/1782262#1782262

Comment: The CGAL library defines and implements the concept of circulators https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Circulator/classCirculator.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were me, I'd have `operator++` notice the terminal condition, and set `c` to some sentinal value:

```
circulator(circ& c) : c(&c), start(&c) {}
circulator& operator++() { c = c->next; if(c==start) c=nullptr; return *this; }
```

Usage:

```
circulator begin{a}, end;
while(begin != end) {
  begin++;
}
```

Note that this usage defines the end iterator as holding a nullptr, which means that you can't do this:

```
circulator end;
--end;
```

Comment: That would also require some trickery to make `operator--` work on `end`, which is required by an iterator. Nice thinking otherwise.

Comment: `operator--` is not required for a ForwardIterator, only for a BidirectionalIterator. Which do you require?

Comment: I'll add the `bidirectional` requirement to the question. I though it was obvious as `circ` had a `prev` and `next` pointer and my original circulator had too.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, "circulator" means a circular iteration adapter for a linear structure. What you desire is really an inverse adapter: it takes a circular structure, and presents a linear iterator that has a beginning and an end - such concepts simply don't apply to circular iterators or circular structure.

So, to avoid confusion, I'll refer to the iterator as a `circ_iterator`. The true `circulator` for your circular structure is trivial, and must not care about any ends or beginnings.

The desired functionality can be had by tagging the iterator:

1. The idiomatic way of getting `start`/`end` iterators for type `T` is via `begin` and `end` in the namespace where `T` lives, or via member functions of the same name. The instantiation `circ_iterator end{a}` would be non-idiomatic. Instead, overload `begin` and `end` on  `circ&`. Both return an iterator pointing to the argument. `begin` tags the iterator `Default`, and `end` tags the iterator `End`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8164567/1329652) for details.
2. Only the end iterator is special, and all of the typical iterator semantics can be had by adding a small, three-valued tag to the iterator. Its values are:

   - End: the iterator originated as a result of `end`;
   - Inc: the iterator did not originate from `end` and has been most recently incremented;
   - Default: otherwise.

   An iterator obtained from `end` will retain its `End` tag forever. Otherwise, an iterator starts with the `Default` tag, and switches to `Inc` on increment, and back to `Default` on decrement.

Note that `begin` and `end` can never be the same, since there's no way for the circular container to have a zero size: a `circ` item always holds at least one data item. You could, of course represent an absence of a `circ` instance using a null iterator that compares equal to any other null iterator.

The increment operation is special, since the only legal way to approach the end iterator is by incrementing. When doing so, the following must hold:

1. You're not incrementing starting at end, since that's illegal.
2. Only after an increment you might be before the end, or at the end.

Thus, the iterators are identical when their pointers are identical, and:

- the other iterator is not tagged End, or
- this iterator is not tagged Default (it must be itself End or Inc - recently incremented).

Since the tag is small (2 bits wide), you can assume, or statically assert, that the `circ` type is aligned to 4 bytes *and* the platform-specific `uintptr_t`<->`*circ` conversions are "sane", and using the tagged pointer trick to retain the tag in the least significant bits of the pointer. I provide both the version that employs the tagged pointer trick, and one that doesn't.

Finally, it's much easier to implement iterators by deriving from `boost::iterator_facade`. I'm leaving the implementation of `const_circ_iterator` as an exercise to the reader. [It is well documented](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html#a-constant-node-iterator).

The code compiles on MSVC2012 and also on LLVM 6.

First, let's deal with the tagged pointers - this is a very basic implementation, but will do for our purposes.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/circ-

iterator-9993713
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/operators.hpp>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T, bool merge_tag = false, typename tag_type = uint8_t> class tagged_ptr;

template <typename T, typename tag_type> class tagged_ptr<T, true, tag_type> {
    uintptr_t ptr;
    typedef std::numeric_limits<uintptr_t> lim;
    inline static uintptr_t ptr_of(T* p) {
        assert(tag_of(p) == 0);
        return uintptr_t(p);
    }
    inline static uintptr_t tag_mask() { return 3; }
    inline uintptr_t ptr_only() const { return ptr & (lim::max() - tag_mask()); }
    inline static tag_type tag_of(T* p) { return ((tag_type)(uintptr_t)p) & tag_mask(); }
    inline tag_type tag_only() const { return ptr & tag_mask(); }
public:
    tagged_ptr(T* p, tag_type t) : ptr(ptr_of(p) | t) { assert(t <= tag_mask()); }
    tagged_ptr(const tagged_ptr & other) : ptr(other.ptr) {}
    operator T*() const { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr_only()); }
    T* operator->() const { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr_only()); }
    tagged_ptr & operator=(T* p) { ptr = tag_only() | ptr_of(p); return *this; }
    tag_type tag() const { return tag_only(); }
    void set_tag(tag_type tag) { assert(tag <= tag_mask()); ptr = tag | ptr_only(); }
};

template <typename T, typename tag_type> class tagged_ptr<T, false, tag_type> {
    T* ptr;
    tag_type m_tag;
public:
    tagged_ptr(T* p, tag_type t) : ptr(p), m_tag(t) {}
    tagged_ptr(const tagged_ptr & other) : ptr(other.ptr), m_tag(other.m_tag) {}
    operator T*() const { return ptr; }
    T* operator->() const { return ptr; }
    tagged_ptr & operator=(T* p) { ptr = p; return *this; }
    tag_type tag() const { return m_tag; }
    void set_tag(tag_type tag) { m_tag = tag; }
};
```

The `circ` class can have some convenience constructors to make constructing circular lists easier, and to avoid the mistake you made in your question (`a.prev = &a` is wrong).

```
struct circ : private boost::noncopyable {
    unsigned int i;
    circ* next;
    circ* prev;
    explicit circ(int i) : i(i), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {}
    circ(int i, circ& prev) : i(i), next(nullptr), prev(&prev) {
        prev.next = this;
    }
    circ(int i, circ& prev, circ& next) : i(i), next(&next), prev(&prev) {
        prev.next = this;
        next.prev = this;
    }
};
```

The circ_iterator is then:

```
class circ_iterator;
circ_iterator end(circ& c);

class circ_iterator
        : public boost::iterator_facade<
        circ_iterator, circ, boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag
        >
{
    tagged_ptr<circ> c;
    enum { Default, Inc, End };
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
    friend circ_iterator end(circ&);
    struct end {};
    circ_iterator(circ& c_, end) : c(&c_, End) {}

    circ& dereference() const { return *c; }
    void increment() {
        c = c->next;
        if (c.tag() != End) c.set_tag(Inc);
    }
    void decrement() {
        c = c->prev;
        if (c.tag() != End) c.set_tag(Default);
    }
    bool equal(const circ_iterator & other) const {
        return this->c == other.c &&
                (other.c.tag() != End || this->c.tag() != Default);
    }
public:
    circ_iterator() : c(nullptr, Default) {}
    circ_iterator(circ& c_) : c(&c_, Default) {}
    circ_iterator(const circ_iterator& other) : c(other.c) {}
};

circ_iterator begin(circ& c) { return circ_iterator(c); }
circ_iterator end(circ& c) { return circ_iterator(c, circ_iterator::end()); }
```

Finally, a simple demonstration:

```
int main()
{
    circ a(0), b(1, a), c(2, b), d(3, c, a);
    assert(end(a) == end(a));
    assert(++--end(a) == end(a));
    for (auto it = begin(a); it != end(a); ++it) {
        std::cout << it->i << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "*" << std::endl;
    for (auto it = ++begin(a); it != --end(a); ++it) {
        std::cout << it->i << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "*" << std::endl;
    for (auto & c : a)
        std::cout << c.i << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
*
1
2
*
0
1
2
3
```