# Is stl list provide a circular container

Tags: c++, stl

Based on these question:
[Is there a standard cyclic iterator in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616643/is-there-a-standard-cyclic-iterator-in-c), [Iterators for    circular structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993713/iterators-for-circular-structures) and [Easiest way to make a cyclic iterator    (circulator)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782019/easiest-way-to-make-a-cyclic-iterator-circulator) 
I assumed that there is no circular iterator in STL but then I found that the following code implements a circular like iterator,
I did not find any documentation describing this behavior, so I decided to make sure about it here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    list<int> firstlist {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto it = firstlist.begin(); 
    for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
        if(it == firstlist.end()) {
            cout << "==end==" << endl;;
            it++;
        }
        cout << i << ": " << *it++ << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
3: 4
4: 5
==end==
5: 1
6: 2
7: 3
8: 4
9: 5
==end==
10: 1
11: 2
12: 3
13: 4
14: 5
==end==
15: 1
16: 2
17: 3
18: 4
19: 5
```

Here is a link to execution: [code](http://cpp.sh/9vcbk)

Comment: Use debug mode (`-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` with libstdc++ (gcc) for instance) and it won't let you.