# Is there something like circular_advance avaliable in std or boost?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, stdadvance

lets say I want to go through container in a circular way:

> idx = 0, idx =1 .. idx = size()-1, idx =0, idx =1 ...

Is there a way to do in with std or boost? 
I know that algorithms operate on ranges not on containers so I guess Im out of luck, but I just wanted to check.

P.S. No need for manual implementations, it is trivial(if you dont forget about seq points :P ), just

```
curr_idx= (curr_idx+1) % my_cont.size()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any function like that, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1782262/160206) shows how to use [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) to create an iterator adaptor that cycles over a collection.