# static allocated data structures

Tags: c++, data-structures, memory-management, real-time

I'm working on a existing embedded system (memory is limited, Flash is limited,
...) with an RT OS. All data structures have a fixed size and are allocated
at "compile time" and are therefore suited for RT. There is no dynamic memory
allocation. The programming language is C++, but there is no STL available. I
like to replace some of the data structures especially LinkedList, Vector and
Map with some more generic variants.

The closest I've seen so far is the following framework:
http://apfw.sourceforge.net/. The biggest draw back IMHO is that the for a
LinkedList with size N, the default constructor from T is called N times. A
better class should statically allocate sizeof(T)*N bytes.

Does anyone know I library with all of the above constraints?

Comment: It most likely allocates the storage statically in the image. But C++ requires the ctors to be called. How else would you want it to initialize the T instances?

Comment: If this framework supports custom allocators you could try to write your own allocator.

Comment: @sellibitze. Custom allocators are not supported.

Comment: @wilx. First the byte constructor is called. Later the objects are added through a placement new. At least that was the first thing going through my head, if I've to implement something.

Comment: @wilx: The same way `std::vector` does this. Its capacity is all raw bytes, with constructors invoked (via placement new) as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered passing your own allocator (allocating from a static pool) to STL containers?

Other than that, I don't think anything like this exists. You might want to look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563591/) to get started with a static vector class. If you do this, consider to make it Open Source.

Comment: Currently the target has no STL. If there was enough Flash available (the download link is a serial line with ca. 2 KiBytes/s, therefore even if I add more Flash I've a problem) I guess the STL with an O(1) memory allocator (e.g. http://rtportal.upv.es/rtmalloc/) would be ok. I've to admit that I never tried to chop up the STL in small pieces.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fixing the size of the LinkedList, why not just create your own simple class and back it by an array?

Comment: Because there are maybe 10% of the methods needed, compared what the STL provides, that would be feasible. I guess if no one already knows a library I'll write my own class, post it here, and let the experts decide, what I f..... up.

Answer (score 1):

May I recommend you the following:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Containers.aspx

It's an article I've written about anoter design of container classes. One of the biggest advantages of them is that **allocating** the data and **storing** it in the container are separated.

You may for instance declare your static data at compile-time, and then in run-time insert/remove it to/from the list/tree/etc.