# POD implications for a struct which holds an standard library container

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, std

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430801/c-guarantee-and-name-for-pod-like-data-memcpy-capable) question recently. My goal is to understand how the C++ compiler views struct definitions which hold standard library containers such as std::vector.

[Ben Voigt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5453372/763053) answer to the linked question cites the following from the C++0x standard:

> ....
>
> A *trivial class* is a class that has a trivial default constructor (12.1) and is trivially copyable.
>
> [ *Note:*  In particular, a trivially copyable or trivial class does not have virtual functions or virtual base
>   classes. — *end note* ]
>
> A *standard-layout class* is a class that:
>
> - **has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference**,
>
> ....

I'm almost certain that the bolded text implies that the following is undefined behavior

```
struct A 
{
    std::vector< SomeType > myVec;
    int myC;  
    A( int c ) : myC : (c) {}
};

int main( void )
{
    A one( 1 );
    A two( 2 );

    SomeType k, z;
    one.myVec.push_back( k );
    two.myVec.push_back( z );

    memcpy( &two, &one, sizeof( A ) ); // bad juju
}
```

And the same would be the case for *any* type which is from the standard library, including simpler types such as `std::string`. This would be due to the nature of the library's design, given its large usage of inheritance and template programming.

So, while `struct A` would resemble that of a POD type, the fact that it *contains* that standard library type automatically invalidates it from that category, as far as the compiler is concerned.

Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: No, `A` is not trivially copyable. And neither `std::vector` nor `std::string` is something I would call "simple". A select few standard library classes are guaranteed to be trivially copyable.

Comment: Standard layout and PODness aren't relevant to what you're asking about; `A` isn't trivially copyable, and _that_ is the requirement that matters.

Comment: Not only is it not a POD "as far as the compiler is concerned", but it isn't as far as the *standard* is concerned; its members are not all trivially copyable. It has nothing to do with layout, inheritance, templates, or being "simple".

Comment: "STL library" generally is a harmless label, but here it is quite misleading. The STL was integrated into the Standard Library about 2 decades ago, but `std::string` for instance came from somewhere else.

Comment: @MSalters Even more so with "STL library". Since that sounds like it's a disambiguation to mean the "STL" and not the "standard library" (as the acronym would be redundant otherwise.)

Comment: `My goal is to understand how the C++ compiler views struct definitions` This sentence doesn't make much sense to me. Obviously compilers interpret the standard differently and are subject to bugs. Similarly with `as far as the compiler is concerned.` If you want an answer that addresses the standard  (and not a specific implementation), why are you bringing the compiler into this? Furthermore, the C++ standard library, a compiler and standard library implementations are three different things. I think your question needs to be reworded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Your basic assumptions are flawed. "Standard layout" is not related to templates. E.g. `std::pair<T1, T2>` has standard layout if and only if both `T1` and `T2` do. Same goes for `std::array<T,N>`

However, none of the *Containers* have standard layout. The whole point of their allocators is to have advanced memory management.

Comment: They may or may not be standard layout. They are definitely not trivially copyable.

Comment: @T.C. `std::array` is though and `static_assert(std::is_pod<std::array<int, 1>>())` passes on GCC 6.4, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674247/is-stdarrayt-s-guaranteed-to-be-pod-if-t-is-pod