# hpp files && implememtning a class extending vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have 2 questions.

1. does any one know what an hpp file is? Why would someone do that?
2. I am trying to implement a class that extends vector

But I want to use all the original functions and add on actions for each function.
So I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#ifndef _MY_PERSONAL_VECTOR
#define _MY_PERSONAL_VECTOR


class PersonalVec: public std::vector<int>{

public:
    PersonalVec();

    void push_back(const int& Val);


};

#endif
```

and in the cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "PersonalVec.hpp"

using namespace std;

PersonalVec::PersonalVec(): std::vector<int>(){
}

void PersonalVec::push_back(const int& Val):vector<int>::push_back(Val){
    cout<<"new improved vector";
}
```

So in the function push_back I am trying to call the vector push_back but it is not working.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: By the way, your include guard is broken. All names starting with underscore followed by a capital letter are *reserved*. They may conflict with names used or defined by the compiler or the standard library. (The same is true for any name containing a double underscore, and for underscore followed by lower-case letter at namespace scope. Easiest solution is to just avoid using leading underscores.)

Answer (score 6):

> 1. Does anyone know what an `hpp` file is?

**.hpp** is a commonly used file extension for C++ header files.

> 2. I am trying to implement a class that extends `vector`

[You probably don't want to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922248/is-there-any-real-risk-to-deriving-from-the-c-stl-containers).  The standard library containers do not have virtual destructors and are not intended to be derived from.  You should prefer to:

- use composition (have a container as a member variable), or
- extend the functionality using non-member functions

Which is better depends entirely on what you need to do.

Comment: Inheriting an STL container is not dangerous.  It's using a pointer to an STL container that would be dangerous.

Comment: @aschepler:  It isn't dangerous per se, but it is dangerous because it makes it really easy to do something really dumb.

Comment: It's still my opinion that using a `vector<int>*` is usually dumb whether there are derived classes or not.  But the key word there is "opinion".

Comment: @aschepter: inheriting isn't dangerous, it just creates a type that is dangerous to *use*. `std::vector` is designed so that it is basically safe to use, even if you create pointers to it. Inheriting from a standard container destroys that guarantee. Now you can perform an otherwise perfectly normal operation, which makes your vector derivative fail.

Answer (score 2):

.hpp is a naming convention, sometimes used to distinguish header files containing template classes from non-template classes, or to distinguish C code from C++ code.

You need to encapsulate the vector and delegate to it.

```
class PersonalVec{

public:
    PersonalVec();

    void push_back(const int& Val);

private:
    std::vector<int> data;

};

void PersonalVec::push_back(const int& Val){
    cout<<"new improved vector";
    data.push_back(Val);
}
```

Comment: The poster wants to use the methods defined by vector<int> by default.  Encapsulation wouldn't do that (except by manually forwarding every public method of vector<int>).

Comment: @aschepler - understood, see @James McNellis's answer for rationale behind my suggestion here.

Answer (score 0):

A *.hpp file is a header file.  It's no different from an *.h file, except that some people like to name them that way so they can immediately know whether the file is a C header or C++ header.

You can only use `:stuff()` that way in the definition of a constructor.  Your method definition should be:

```
void PersonalVec::push_back(const int& Val) {
  vector<int>::push_back(Val);
  cout << "new improved vector";
}
```