# Access to the iterator,vector in the Inventory.h

Tags: c++, vector, header

Hey im using a vector plus its iterator.  I have it in the Inventory.h file along with the Inventory.cpp.  I want to know is can i call it directly so i can get access to the vector library functions such as push,pop etc... Because at the moment i cant.  Can someone help me with this.

Here is my code:

**Inventory.h**

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Inventory.h
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; 
class Inventory
{
public:
    //Constructor
    Inventory();

    //Methods.
    string add(string item);
    void displayInventory();
    void showInventory();
private:
    //Data members
   vector<string> inventory;
   vector<string>::iterator myIterator;
   vector<string>::const_iterator iter;
    };


#endif //INVENTORY_H
```

**Inventory.cpp**

```
#include "Inventory.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>   //  To enable the use of the vector class.
#include <string>


using namespace std;



Inventory::Inventory()
{

}

string Inventory :: add(string item)
{
inventory.push_back(item);
return item;
}

void Inventory:: showInventory()
{
char input[80];
    cin >> input;
    char inventoryRequest[] = "i";
    int invent = strcmp (input,inventoryRequest);
    //compare the player input to inventoryRequest (i) to see if they want to look at inventory.
    if(invent == 0)
    {
        displayInventory();
    }


}
void Inventory:: displayInventory()
{
//vector<string> inventory;
    cout<< "You have " << inventory.size() << " items.\n";
    cout << "\n******Inventory******";
    cout<< "\nYour items:\n";
    for (int i= 0; i< inventory.size(); ++i)
        cout<< inventory[i] << endl;
}
```

**What i want to be able to do:**

```
int main()
{
Inventory inventory;
inventory.push_back();


}
```

**Errors**

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > & __thiscall Inventory::GetContainer(void)" (?GetContainer@Inventory@@QAEAAV?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function _main   C:\Users\Conor\Documents\College\DKIT - Year 2 - Repeat\DKIT - Year 2 - Semester 1 - Repeat\Games Programming\MaroonedCA2\MaroonedCA2\Main.obj  MaroonedCA2
Error   3   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Conor\Documents\College\DKIT - Year 2 - Repeat\DKIT - Year 2 - Semester 1 - Repeat\Games Programming\MaroonedCA2\Debug\MaroonedCA2.exe MaroonedCA2
```

Comment: Yes,  you can rename `Inventory :: add`  to `Inventory :: push_back`

Comment: inventory.add is the same.  But like doing it like this(using the add method)  i have not got the ability to use the iterator and i would have to write a function for everything i would like to use from the vector class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to add a `push_back` and the other vector methods you want to replicate to your inventory class:

```
class Inventory
{
public:
    //Constructor
    Inventory();

    //Methods.
    std::string add(std::string item);
    void displayInventory();
    void showInventory();
    void push_back(const std::string& s) { inventory.push_back(s); }
private:
    //Data members
   std::vector<std::string> inventory;
   std::vector<std::string>::iterator myIterator;
   std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter;
};
```

Note that inheriting **privately** from `std::vector` could also be an option. It is not 100% safe, but it is hard to find scenarios where it could pose a problem. Inheriting publicly is a definite no-no. This example shows how to expose part of `std::vector`'s privately inherited public interface:

```
class Inventory : private std::vector<std::string>
{
 public:
  // make a selection of the vector's methods public for this class.
  using std::vector<std::string>::push_back;
  using std::vector<std::string>::pop_back;
  using std::vector<std::string>::begin;
  using std::vector<std::string>::end;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inherityour class from std::vector:

```
class Inventory : public std::vector<std::string> {
   public:
      Inventory();
      void displayInventory();
      void showInventory();
      // [...] 
}
```

Then in your code you should be able to do things like:

```
int main()
{
    Inventory inv;
    inv.push_back("item 1");
    inv.push_back("item 2");
    for (Inventor::iterator it = inv.begin(); it != inv.end(); ++it)
           std::cerr << *it << ' ';
    std::cerr << std::endl;
}
```

Through inheritance you can avoid to redefine methods, iterators and so on.

Comment: Bad advice. What happens if someone destroys `Inventory` object via `vector<string>` poiner?

Comment: @gabry brilliant that is exactly what i wanted to do thanks very much.

Comment: @Pendo826, just don't come here tomorrow asking "why Inventory class is memory leaking" %)

Comment: Warning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922248/is-there-any-real-risk-to-deriving-from-the-c-stl-containers

Comment: @aleguna - Ok is there another way to do it?

Comment: @aleguna: depending on the use-case there may be little chance of this happening. Are you forbidding to extend any STL class which doesn't have a virtual destructor?

Comment: While this will work, and it's even fairly safe in practice because you'll likely not try to delete a instance of this class via a pointer to it's base class, that there is a potential bug there, and also it's generally considered a bad idea to inherit from standard containers for this reason and general style. It'd probably prefered to contain an instance of the vector and then write your own push_back etc that delegate to that instance.

Comment: inventory.push_back("Hello");  This does not add Stone to the vector.  Whereas my original add function.  inventory.add("Sword"); Works.

Comment: @Pendo826: It looks like you want to give Inventory class the interface of a STL vector. It looks like an 'object Adapter' is what you need.

Is this inventory class something that you can't change?

Comment: @J99 - So writing my own functions is common to do like my add Function ?

Comment: @Antoine, I am not forbidding anything, just giving a warning.

Comment: @aleguna  Memory leaking is something i know nothing about,  So i appreciate the advice.

Comment: @Pendo826, well then you should read about memory in c++ before going any further, topic is too broad to be discussed in comments

Comment: The are not uncommon, and yes they are a pain and a bit ugly, but often better than the alternatives.

Comment: @Pendo826 note that private inheritance is much less dangerous than public inheritance here. I would say it is a viable solution here. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues/improvement areas with this code snippet. However, for the specific one you asked, please note that 'push_back' is not a member function of Inventory class. So you are getting the compiler error.

You need to call inventory.add for this.

Comment: But like what i mean is, is there anyway i can modify my code so that i can use the push_back function without having to use my add() function.

Comment: Would it be fine in your case if you provide a 'getter' for the 'inventory' member?

Comment: Ive never used getters in C++ before.  But i dont think there would be a problem with it no.

Comment: no. no problem language wise. But you would have to evaluate if it is appropriate in your context. So, you can have a member function like std::vector<string> &GetContainer() which returns the reference to the member 'inventory'. Then your call would look like 'Inventory.GetContainer().push_back'. But that does not make it look like 'inventory.push_back' for sure

Comment: Oh i see and would i put  std::vector<string> &GetContainer()  in the inventory.h or the inventory.cpp ?