# C++: How does it work alias members class?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, reference, alias

in the following code:

```
class prova: public std::map< int,int >
{
 public:
 prova():a(5){}
 int a;

};

int main()
{
 std::vector<prova> p;
 prova obj;
 p.push_back(obj); 
 return 0;
}
```

it works without problem;
If I add a reference member

```
class prova: public std::map< int,int >
{
 public:
 prova():a(5){}
 int a;
 int& b=a;
};

int main()
{
 std::vector<prova> p;
 prova obj;
 p.push_back(obj); 
 return 0;
}
```

I have

```
warning: non-static data member initializers only     available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]|
/home/andrea/Scaricati/prova.cpp||In instantiation of ‘void 
std::vector<_Tp,_Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, const _Tp&) 
[with _Tp = prova; _Alloc = std::allocator<prova>; 
std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<prova*, std::vector<prova> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = prova*]’:|
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h|913|required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = prova; _Alloc = std::allocator<prova>;   std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = prova]’|
/home/andrea/Scaricati/prova.cpp|19|required from here|
/home/andrea/Scaricati/prova.cpp|4|error: non-static reference member ‘int& prova::b’,     can’t use default assignment operator|
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc|335|note: synthesized method ‘prova&     prova::operator=(const prova&)’ first required here     
|||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 4 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

no problems adding -std=g++11 like suggested from warning. 
If I remove the vector declaration I have just the warning without the error.
Why C++ old standard can't do it? what is the problem with references attributes? is there a system to do same things without using c++11 standard? I try

```
class prova: public std::map< int,int >
{
 public:
 prova():a(5),b(a){}
 int a;
 int &b;
};
```

but I get errors. Why this? thanks!

Comment: non-static data member initializers is a C++11 feature. Anyway if you maintain self-references you need to write the copy ctor and assignment operator yourself or things will get messy.

Comment: "Why C++ old standard can't do it?": as stated in the warning, "non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11".  Honestly, I'm not sure why it's not an error - I don't know what the compiler in pre-C++11 mode does with the non-static member initializer.

Comment: Also, inheriting from a standard template library is a bit frowned upon  http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4143/Working-with-the-Final-Class-in-C.htm

and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922248/is-there-any-real-risk-to-deriving-from-the-c-stl-containers

Comment: ok..but why error on the iterator?!

Comment: @volperossa: because `push_back()` from an lvalue needs to copy the element and as the error states (granted - it's buried in a bunch of noise; that's still a big problem with C++ template errors): "error: non-static reference member `'int& prova::b'`, can’t use default assignment operator".  So, as T.C. mentioned, you'll need to define your own copy operations in order to correctly handle the reference.

Answer (score 2):

You get a warning because your compiler is smart enough to know the syntax of C++11. In C++ such syntax `int& b= a` is called an **In-class member initializer** and in previous standards, this could only be done with `static const` variables. C++11 relaxes those constraints.

From [Stroustrup's page](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init):

> In C++98, only `static const` members of integral types can be
>   initialized in-class, and the initializer has to be a constant
>   expression. These restrictions ensure that we can do the
>   initialization at compile-time.
>
> For example:

```
int var = 7;

class X {       
    static const int m1 = 7;        // ok       
    const int m2 = 7;               // error: not static        
    static int m3 = 7;              // error: not const         
    static const int m4 = var;      // error: initializer not constant expression 
    static const string m5 = "odd"; // error: not integral type         
    // ...  
};
```

> The basic idea for C++11 is to allow a non-static data member to be
>   initialized where it is declared (in its class). A constructor can
>   then use the initializer when run-time initialization is needed.
>   Consider:

```
class A {   
public: 
    int a = 7;  
};
```

> This is equivalent to:

```
class A {   
public:         
    int a;      
    A() : a(7) {}   
};
```

Comment: The two `A`'s are not strictly equivalent in C++14. The first is an aggregate; the second one isn't.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I removed any mention of C++14 in my post.

Comment: ok but with this

    class prova: public std::map< int,int >
    {
    public:
    prova():a(5),b(a){}
    int a;
    int &b;

   };

i get error

Comment: error: non-static reference member ‘int& prova::b’, can’t use default assignment operator|

Comment: @volperossa: Not sure, could be your compiler. Works for me in VS2013. (I removed the inheritance from std::map, but that shouldn't matter)